# Retuning a dynamic domain in Odoo server action

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am returning a dynamic domain from a server action in Odoo with the following code. Please note I am using a hosted version of Odoo online, so I am doing this through the Odoo UI. Actions are returned by assigning `action = {...}`:

```py
action = {
    'domain': {
        'route_id': [('id', 'in', record.x_all_route_ids.ids)]
    }
}
```

This server action is triggered when the `product_id` field changes for a `sales.order.line`. When viewing a sales order, if I change the product_id for one of the sales order lines, the domain for the `route_id` field is updated as expected.

However, the domain is changed for all of the `route_id` fields in the sale order line tree view. In other words, if there are 3 lines in the order, and I change the product_id for one of them, I want the domain to change for just that line's route_id field, not every route_id field in the sale order.

Is what I'm seeing the expected behavior, and is there any way to accomplish what I want instead?

Here is the compute method for the `x_all_route_ids` field:

```
for record in self:
    routes = record.product_id.x_all_route_ids

    if not record.product_id.x_is_preorder_active:
       # If the product has no stock, only keep routes that do not require stock
        if record.product_id.x_sellable_qty <= 0:
            routes = routes.filtered(lambda r: r.x_needs_available_inventory == False)

        # If a vendor is unavailable, remove it's route from the list
        for info in record.product_id.seller_ids:
            if not info.x_is_active:
                route = self.env['stock.location.route'].search([('x_is_vendor_dropship_route','=', True), ('x_vendor_id', '=', info.name.id)])
                routes = routes - route

    record['x_available_routes'] = [(6, False, routes.ids)]
```

And here is the code for the extension view:

```
<data>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='route_id']" position="before">
        <field name="x_available_routes" invisible="1"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='route_id']" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="domain">[('id', 'in', x_available_routes[0][2])]</attribute>
    </xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo you can directly assign values.

**record.x_available_routes=routes.ids**

```
for record in self:
    routes = record.product_id.x_all_route_ids
    if not record.product_id.x_is_preorder_active:
       # If the product has no stock, only keep routes that do not require stock
        if record.product_id.x_sellable_qty <= 0:
            routes = routes.filtered(lambda r: r.x_needs_available_inventory == False)

        # If a vendor is unavailable, remove it's route from the list
        for info in record.product_id.seller_ids:
            if not info.x_is_active:
                route = self.env['stock.location.route'].search([('x_is_vendor_dropship_route','=', True), ('x_vendor_id', '=', info.name.id)])
                routes = routes - route

    record.x_available_routes=routes.ids
```

In xml you should use following code.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='route_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="domain">[('route_id', 'in', x_available_routes[0][2])]</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: I don't think you can write domains that way. The `.ids` attribute does not exist on the client. From what I've seen you would have to do: `<field name="route_id" domain="[('id', 'in', line.x_all_route_ids[0][2])]"/>` because the client stores the field in `write` format. For example: `[[6, false, [1,2,3]]`. I used this method originally, but would get an error upon first adding a new SO line and trying to open the route_id dropdown. Only after saving the line would it work correctly.

Comment: What is `line` in your code? Line is not defined anywhere in the view. Also, I am not able to get the syntax in your first example working. When I click the field to open the route_id dropdown, I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Expected "]", got "(name)"`

Comment: I have edited my answer line means you sale order line. Can you try again ?

Comment: The first example does not work. Same error. I didn't think you could use python expressions like that in the domain.

Comment: Now which error are you getting & what is field type many2many or one2many  ?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Expected "]", got "(name)"`. As far as I know the client does not have the actual objects or record sets. You can't do things like `.id` or iterate through `x_all_route_ids`. That field is given to the client as a set of many2many write commands. The `x_all_route_ids` field is many2many, and `route_id` is many2one.

Comment: That is another way to set the field's value but it doesn't change the outcome. The route_id field gets the appropriate domain if the line already exists, meaning, it has already been saved to the SO. However, if you add a new line to the SO, and click the route_id field to open the dropdown, I get this error: `ValueError: Invalid domain term (u'id', u'in', {u'active': True, u'name': u'Stock', u'sequence': 9})`

Comment: Can you write x_available_routes field syntax ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140089/discussion-between-flyingl123-and-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd).